# Website text larger and smaller

Tags: html, font-size

On my website, i want to have to buttons, one to make the text size on larger, and one to make it one smaller!

Does anyone know how to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that you can't do what you want with plain HTML. You need JavaScript for that.

This blog post explains exactly what you want:

- [Change Text Size On Click With JavaScript](http://davidwalsh.name/change-text-size-onclick-with-javascript)

So in your case with two buttons you would need something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
        document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
    }
    document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="resizeText(1)" />
<input type="button" onclick="resizeText(-1)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers have this functionality built in. You can zoom / increase text size and this works for all the pages. Also the users are more familiar resizing the text this way than any custom controls.

Comment: I'm not sure the average, non-geek user would know how to do this in their browser. You have to navigate through a menu vs. just clicking this guy's button.

Comment: But you learn it once and it works for all sites (and you don't have to navigate through a menu, most browsers provide other UIs for it, which are pretty consistent across different applications)